# JS async helper function that makes delay is running slower that it should

Tags: javascript, performance, quicksort

I'm writing a sorting algorithm visualiser in javascript. So far the code is working, however there are performance issues.

I'm trying to make it so that swap function takes 1 ms (speed.value) to run. However, other than first 4 swaps every swap call on average takes 4 ms to resolve.The code looks something like this:

```
async function bubbleSort(arr, start, end) {
  for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
    for (j = start; j < end - i - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[j].val > arr[j + 1].val) {
        await swap(arr, j, j + 1);
      }
    }
    j = 0;
  }
}

async function swap(arr, a, b) {
  var t3 = performance.now();
  await delay(speed.value);
  Bars_c.push({ a, b });
  var temp = arr[a].val;
  arr[a].val = arr[b].val;
  arr[b].val = temp;
  swapOnGraph(arr, a, b);
  var t4 = performance.now();
  console.log(t4 - t3);
}



function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Without "await delay(speed.value)" each swap takes less than a millisecond to complete. And testing just that function shows that its working as intended outside of swap so delay() rewrites seem pointless. How can I change the code so that each swap takes 1 ms to run.

Comment: Browsers have a minimum delay time of around 16ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetTimeout method is indeed the bottleneck .It can be proved by running this code:

```
var results = 0,
iterations = 1000,
i = 0;

function go() {
    var fn = function () {
            results += new Date().getTime() - d;
            i += 1;
            if (i < iterations) {
                go();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        },
        d = new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(fn, 0);
}
```

Average time will depend on the browser and as Pointy sad it can reach up to 16 ms. For this question I found the solution on [stack-exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47889/alternative-to-setinterval-and-settimeout). As this is a visualisation project and not a timer suggested solution works great.